# what is wrong in this c code as total__marks always prints zero irrespective of the input?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()  
{  
    int n;
    float percentage;
    int marks,total_marks;
    printf("enter the number of subjects");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    total_marks=0;

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        
        printf("enter your marks\n");
        scanf("%d",&marks);
        total_marks+=marks;

    }
    printf("%f\n",total_marks);
    percentage=(total_marks)/((float)n*100.0);
    printf("%f\n",percentage);

    if(percentage<0.5){
        printf("d grade");
    }
    else if(percentage>=0.5 && percentage<0.6){
        printf("c grade");
    }
    else if(percentage>=0.6 && percentage<0.8){
        printf("b grade");
    }
    else if(percentage>=0.8 && percentage<1){
        printf("a grade");
    }
    return 0;
    }
```

why is total_marks always printing zero but percentage gives the correct output?
i tried giving many inputs but total_marks is always printing zero but the percentage is giving value
which means in percentage correct value of total_marks is  being taken but why is this happening?

Comment: `%f` is not the `printf` format string for `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

regarding:

```
printf("%f\n",total_marks);
```

This is trying to print an integer as a float (which does not work)

Suggest:

```
printf("%d\n",total_marks);
```

Note: if your compiler did not warn you of this problem, then enable the warnings.

Note: for `gcc` the needed warnings can be enabled via:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=c11
```

Comment: Yes, warnings can help a lot. I get: `warning: format '%f' expects argument of type 'double', but argument 2 has type 'int' [-Wformat=]`

Comment: simple, your compiler told you right.  i.E. do not ignore the warnings